# Bayesian statistics

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, map-estimation, improper-prior

Assuming I have that $Y_i\mid \mu$ is an iid ~ $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, for $i \in (1,\dotsc,n)$ with $\sigma_i$ known and improper prior $\pi(\mu)=1$ for all $\mu$.
i. How can I derive a formula for the MAP of $\mu$.
ii. Given that, $n=3$, $Y_1=12$, $Y_2=10$, $Y_3=22$, $\sigma_1= \sigma_2=3$ and $\sigma_3=10$. Compute the MAP estimate of $\mu$.

I know I will have to take the log of the Normal distribution + log of the prior, differentiate and set to zero. However the questions says prior is improper and 1. Do I only therefore do the log of the likelihood because log of 1 is zero?

I don't know how to go by ii, if I cant figure I out.

Comment: Would you mind refining your question a bit? as there seem to be some typos. Also is $Y_i \vert \mu, \sigma_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2_i)$?

Answer (score 0):

By assuming $Y_i\vert\mu, \sigma^2_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2_i)$ and $\pi(\mu) = 1$, the posterior $p(\mu \vert \{Y_i, \sigma^2_i\})$ is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
p(\mu \vert \{Y_i, \sigma^2_i\}) &\propto \prod_i \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2_i)(Y_i)\ \times \ \pi(\mu)\\
&\propto\prod_i \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2_i)(Y_i).
\end{aligned}
$$
The log posterior is then given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\log p(\mu \vert \{Y_i, \sigma^2_i\}) = -\sum_i\left[\log\sigma_i + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{Y_i - \mu}{\sigma_i}\right)^2\right] + {\rm constants}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Differentiate it with respect to $\mu$ and equating it with zero gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} \log p(\mu \vert \{Y_i, \sigma^2_i\}) &= \sum_i\frac{Y_i - \mu}{\sigma^2_i}\\
0 &= \sum_i\frac{Y_i - \mu}{\sigma^2_i}\\
0 &= \sum_i\frac{Y_i}{\sigma^2_i} - \sum_i\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}\mu\\
\mu &= \sum_i\frac{Y_i}{\sigma^2_i} \left(\sum_i\frac{1}{\sigma^2_i}\right)^{-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The answer to question ii) can be easily obtained with the above result.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped

Comment: You may want to accept my answer if you find it helpful